# compare distinct values of two column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I used this simple DataFrame to play around a little bit.

```py
     A   B
0   123 abc
1   123 abc
2   123 def
3   456 def
4   456 def
```

I want to check if the value of column B is always the same for each distinct value in column A. For instance '123' in column A, has always to correspond exclusively to 'abc' in column B.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```py
df2 = df[['A','B']].drop_duplicates()
df[(df['A'] == df2['A']) & (df['B'] == df2['B'])].values
```

But I get an error because the index of the DataFrames is not the same.

Then I tried to use a list without success.

```py
test=list(set(df['A']))
for l in test:
    df[df.A== l].B.drop_duplicates()
```

In a small DataFrame like the one that I have used it is easy to see, but how do I easily check it in a larger DataFrame with let say 43K entries?

**EDIT**

Thanks to the answers I know that I can filter for multiple combinations like this:

```py
df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: x['B'].nunique()> 1)
```

Unfortunately this solution returns

```py
     A   B
0   123 abc
1   123 abc
2   123 def
```

I only need an output like

```py
     A   B
0   123 def
```

To find those cases where '123' does not exclusively correspond to 'abc'.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: df.groupby('A').B.nunique(), result more than 1 means they are not always one combination

Comment: do you have two dataframes  and what is your final output, your question is not clear.

Comment: @Akhilesh is the question clearer now?

Comment: @RoKi check updates now

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
df.groupby('A').agg({'B': pd.Series.nunique})
```

or,

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].nunique()
```

As mentioned by Wen-Ben, if counts of B are more than 1 then there are multiple combination.

**UPDATE**

To filter the combinations with multiple counts you can use filter():

```
df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: x['B'].nunique()> 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly doing the job. I have an additional question though: How do I filter or count the multiple combinations in the result?

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific about what you are looking for? Because both of the answers I provided here will give you the count of 1(if there is a single combination) or more(if there are multiple combinations).

Comment: I want to count and filter those cases where the count is >1. So those cases where there are multiple combinations

Comment: @RoKi Check the update. I think you are looking for this solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: yes that helped. Maybe you know if there is a way to only get those cases where '123' in column A does correspond to something else then 'abc' in column B? Cause otherwise it is hard to find those cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby(['A',"B"]).filter(lambda x : len(x)==1)
```

and output will be

```
    A   B
2   123 def
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works for the simple dataframe that I provided. In the larger dataframe with 43K entries the result is a bit different. When I Use df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: x['B'].nunique()> 1) the output is empty. The output of your solution contains two rows. In my opinion the output should be the same

Comment: @RoKi can you show me where it failed - small datasample ?